# Modal ViewController on top of NavigationController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a menuViewController on top of my navigationBar and rootView.

```
menuView = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width*0.4, self.view.frame.size.height)];
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[[self navigationController] presentViewController:menuView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

That is my code, however the view goes black after the animation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` instead of `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.